# Get the amount of bytes read in by javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader

Tags: java, xml, stream

Is there any way to get the amount of bytes read in by the XMLStreamReader, I am using a java.io.FileReader which is passed into the factory that creates the xml reader.  I'm doubting this is possible with the XMLStreamReader but any work around is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are doing somthing like this:

```
final XMLInputFactory inputFactory;
final XMLStreamReader reader;
final InputStream     stream;

inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
stream       = new FileInputStream(file);
reader       = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(stream);
```

You would do something like this:

```
final XMLInputFactory     inputFactory;
final XMLStreamReader     reader;
final InputStream         stream;
final CountingInputStream countingStream;

inputFactory   = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
stream         = new FileInputStream(file);
countingStream = new CountingStream(stream);
reader         = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(countingStream);
```

Where CoutingInputStream is a class that you would need to write/find that keeps track of the number of bytes being read from the underlying InputStream object.

Comment: If someone look for implementation of this solution here is a link to my short implementation on git hub:
https://github.com/kjkrol/useful-code/blob/master/src/main/java/kjkrol/usefulcode/CountingInputStream.java

Answer (score 1):

One popular way is to create a `ByteCountingReader(Reader r);`, I guess I don't have to be any more specific than this :-)